# Proper usage of `tf.scatter_nd` in tensorflow-r1.2

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, python-3.4, tensor

Given `indices` with shape `[batch_size, sequence_len]`, `updates` with shape `[batch_size, sequence_len, sampled_size]`, `to_shape` with shape `[batch_size, sequence_len, vocab_size]`, where `vocab_size` >> `sampled_size`, I'd like to use `tf.scatter` to map the `updates` to a huge tensor with `to_shape`, such that `to_shape[bs, indices[bs, sz]] = updates[bs, sz]`. That is, I'd like to map the `updates` to `to_shape` row by row. Please note that `sequence_len` and `sampled_size` are scalar tensors, while others are fixed. I tried to do the following:

```
new_tensor = tf.scatter_nd(tf.expand_dims(indices, axis=2), updates, to_shape)
```

But I got an error:

```
ValueError: The inner 2 dimension of output.shape=[?,?,?] must match the inner 1 dimension of updates.shape=[80,50,?]: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 2 and 1 for .... with input shapes: [80, 50, 1], [80, 50,?], [3]
```

Could you please tell me how to use `scatter_nd` properly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will have to show how `to_shape` and `indices` are defined. Also, there is a typo in the named parameter `aixs=2`, should be `axis=2`. Is this typo in the original code?

Comment: @E_net4 Thanks for your reply. Yes it is a typo and I fixed it. You can regard these three tensors to be created by placeholder. Except `sequence_len` is a scalar, i.e, it is dynamic, other are fixed.

Comment: Please update your question with that information, in a way that makes it easy to understand and leaves no ambiguity. It is currently not very obvious that `sequence_len` is a scalar tensor.

Comment: There is something unclear or wrong. If `indices` is `[batch_size, sequence_len]` and `to_shape` is `[batch_size, sequence_len, vocab_size]`, then `to_shape[bs, sl, indices[bs, sl]]` would be 1 element, but `updates[bs, sl]` is a vector of size `sampled_size`. Shouldn't `indices` be `[batch_size, sequence_len, sampled_size]`? Or is the content of `indices` the _initial_ position where the content of `updates` is to be placed, or something like that?

Comment: Could you update the code to be runable? Much easier to debug then.

Comment: @jdehesa Thanks for pointing my fault! It's my bad.... I have fixed it. Do you have any idea? Thanks a lot

Comment: Your problem is ill-formed. `to_shape[bs, sl, indices[bs, i]] = updates[bs, sl, i]` But the second dimension of indices go till `sequence_len` while the third dimension of updates go till `sampled_size`

Comment: @user1735003 I have rethought it for a while and edit it. Is it right now?

Answer (score 6):

So assuming you have:

- A tensor `updates` with shape `[batch_size, sequence_len, sampled_size]`.
- A tensor `indices` with shape `[batch_size, sequence_len, sampled_size]`.

Then you do:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Create updates and indices...

# Create additional indices
i1, i2 = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(batch_size),
                     tf.range(sequence_len), indexing="ij")
i1 = tf.tile(i1[:, :, tf.newaxis], [1, 1, sampled_size])
i2 = tf.tile(i2[:, :, tf.newaxis], [1, 1, sampled_size])
# Create final indices
idx = tf.stack([i1, i2, indices], axis=-1)
# Output shape
to_shape = [batch_size, sequence_len, vocab_size]
# Get scattered tensor
output = tf.scatter_nd(idx, updates, to_shape)
```

[`tf.scatter_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd) takes an `indices` tensor, an `updates` tensor and some shape. `updates` is the original tensor, and the shape is just the desired output shape, so `[batch_size, sequence_len, vocab_size]`. Now, `indices` is more complicated. Since your output has 3 dimensions (rank 3), for each of the elements in `updates` you need 3 indices to determine where in the output each element is going to be placed. So the shape of the `indices` parameter should be the same as `updates` with an additional dimension of size 3. In this case, we want the first to dimensions to be the same, but we still have to specify the 3 indices. So we use [`tf.meshgrid`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/meshgrid) to generate the indices that we need and we tile them along the third dimension (the first and second index for each element vector in the last dimension of `updates` is the same). Finally, we stack these indices with the previously created mapping indices and we have our full 3-dimensional indices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my `indicies` is with shape `[batch_size, sequence_length]`. Is it a typo?

Comment: @user5779223 Oh, I though from your comment that was a mistake in the question... Then I still don't understand how the mapping works (if you have made changes to the question can you please point them out?).

Comment: My desired output is `to_shape[bs, sl, indices[bs, i]] = updates[bs, sl, i]` Thus I map the value in `updates` to `to_shape` scalar by scalar

Comment: @user5779223 Ah yes I see your edit now. But then `i` would take values up to `sequence_length`, which doesn't match the size of the third dimension of `updates`, `sampled_size`. I could understand if `indices` had size `[batch_size, sampled_size]` (each batch has its own mapping from `sampled_size` to `vocab_size`) or `[batch_size, sampled_size]` (each sequence in each batch has its own mapping from `sampled_size` to `vocab_size`).

Comment: I have tried your code above. It works well during compiled. But when it runs the train step, it has some issue about calculating gradient: `ValueError: indices.shape[-1] must be <= params.rank, but saw indices shape: [80, ?, 3, 50] and params shape: [80, ?, 76001] for gradients/ScatterNd_grad/GatherNd (op:GatherNd) with input shapes: [80, ?, 76000], [80, ?, 3, 50]`

Comment: Do you have any idea about it? Thanks

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing more, calling [`tf.gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients) in my example seems to work. What is the `.shape` of the two first parameters of `tf.scatter_nd`? Because if it's `[80, ?, 3, 50]` for the first and `[80, ?, 76001]` for the second then it's normal that it doesn't work; the last dimension of the first parameter should have size 3.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for this.

```
def permute_batched_tensor(batched_x, batched_perm_ids):
    indices = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(batched_perm_ids, 2), [1,1,batched_x.shape[2]])

    # Create additional indices
    i1, i2 = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(batched_x.shape[0]),
                     tf.range(batched_x.shape[2]), indexing="ij")
    i1 = tf.tile(i1[:, tf.newaxis, :], [1, batched_x.shape[1], 1])
    i2 = tf.tile(i2[:, tf.newaxis, :], [1, batched_x.shape[1], 1])
    # Create final indices
    idx = tf.stack([i1, indices, i2], axis=-1)
    temp = tf.scatter_nd(idx, batched_x, batched_x.shape)
    return temp
```