# how to change torch.scatter_add to tensorflow function

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need transfer code pytorch to tensorflow
this pytorch code is here [NADST](https://github.com/henryhungle/NADST/blob/master/model/generators.py)

```
    encoded_context = ft['encoded_context2']
    encoded_in_domainslots = ft['encoded_in_domainslots2']
    self.pointer_attn(ft['out_states'], encoded_context, encoded_context, context_mask)
    pointer_attn = self.pointer_attn.attn.squeeze(1)
    p_vocab = F.softmax(vocab_attn, dim = -1)
    context_index = context.unsqueeze(1).expand_as(pointer_attn)
    p_context_ptr = torch.zeros(p_vocab.size()).cuda()
    p_context_ptr.scatter_add_(2, context_index, pointer_attn)
```

I want to change code **"p_context_ptr.scatter_add_(2, context_index, pointer_attn)"** to tensorflow version.

so I use **"tf.compat.v1.tensor_scatter_nd_add()"** of tensorflow function, **but not same operation torch scatter_add_() fucntion**

I'm so try work until now but not found solution my some code like this

```
def get_scatter_add(tensor, indices, updates):
    if indices.shape.rank > 2:
        tensor = tf.compat.v1.reshape(tensor, shape=[-1, tensor.shape[-1]])
        indices = tf.compat.v1.reshape(indices, shape=[-1, indices.shape[-1]])
        updates = tf.compat.v1.reshape(updates, shape=[-1, updates.shape[-1]])

    one_hot_index = tf.compat.v1.one_hot(indices=indices, depth=tensor.shape[-1])

    tile_update = tf.compat.v1.expand_dims(updates, axis=-1)
    updates = tf.compat.v1.to_float(one_hot_index) * tf.compat.v1.to_float(tile_update)
    indices = tf.compat.v1.expand_dims(indices, axis=-1)

    update = tensor.shape[indices.shape[-1]:]
    res = indices.shape[:-1] + update

    scatter = tf.compat.v1.tensor_scatter_nd_add(tensor, indices, updates)
    return scatter
```

but, memory overflow, my variable shape is **tensor.shape()->[1100, 19200], update.shape()->[1100, 900], updates.shape()->[1100, 900]**

how to solve this problem ???

Thank you for your reply

have nice day!!!

Answer (score 1):

I found solution by myself

tensorflow tensor_scatter_nd_add function is some problem vector dimension is expanded for target vector.
but except for one case is same operation to torch scatter_add_ fucntion
this case :

```
import tensorflow as tf
indices = tf.constant([[4], [3], [1], [7]])
updates = tf.constant([9, 10, 11, 12])
tensor = tf.ones([8], dtype=tf.int32)
updated = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add(tensor, indices, updates)
print(updated)
```

it only update, tensor one dimension and indices is rank 2 shape
so i am change shape like above method like this

```
tensor.shape()->reshape[-1]
update.shape()->reshape[-1]
indices.shape()->reshape[-1, 1]
```

this same above case but, we need update index operation but if we have pointer generater for DST task, becuase tensor is vocabulary size of last dimension, so index + vocab size next batch and +vocab*2 next batch

so it function same operation Torch scatter_add_

example:
tensor = [35, 32, vocab_size], indices = [35, 32, 900], update = [35, 32, 900]

**Torch case:**
tensor.scatter_add_(2, indices, update)

**Tensorflow case:**
tensor = my_tensorflow_scatter_add(tensor, indices, update)

this same operation case above variable dimension

my_tensorflow_scatter_add function:

```
    def my_tensorflow_scatter_add(tensor, indices, updates):
    original_tensor = tensor
    # expand index value from vocab size
    indices = tf.compat.v1.reshape(indices, shape=[-1, tf.shape(indices)[-1]])
    indices_add = tf.compat.v1.expand_dims(tf.range(0, tf.shape(indices)[0], 1)*(tf.shape(tensor)[-1]), axis=-1)
    indices += indices_add

    # resize
    tensor = tf.compat.v1.reshape(tensor, shape=[-1])
    indices = tf.compat.v1.reshape(indices, shape=[-1, 1])
    updates = tf.compat.v1.reshape(updates, shape=[-1])

    #check_
    """
    update = tensor.shape[indices.shape[-1]:]
    res = indices.shape[:-1] + update
    """
    #same Torch scatter_add_
    scatter = tf.compat.v1.tensor_scatter_nd_add(tensor, indices, updates)
    scatter = tf.compat.v1.reshape(scatter, shape=[tf.shape(original_tensor)[0], tf.shape(original_tensor)[1], -1])
    return scatter
```

I solved my question problem

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution without flattening all tensors. Assuming the tensor shapes `tensor` = [35, 32, vocab_size], `indices` = [35, 32, 900], `update` = [35, 32, 900] (based on [Proper usage of `tf.scatter_nd` in tensorflow-r1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45162998/proper-usage-of-tf-scatter-nd-in-tensorflow-r1-2)) :

```
def scatter_add(tensor, indices, updates):
    """

    Args:
        tensor: (seq_len, batch_size, vocab_size)
        indices: (seq_len, batch_size, dim)
        updates: (seq_len, batch_size, dim)

    Returns:
        (seq_len, batch_size, vocab_size)
    """
    seq_len, batch_size, dim = indices.shape
    # Create additional indices
    i1, i2 = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(seq_len),
                         tf.range(batch_size), indexing="ij")
    i1 = tf.tile(i1[:, :, tf.newaxis], [1, 1, dim])
    i2 = tf.tile(i2[:, :, tf.newaxis], [1, 1, dim])
    # Create final indices
    idx = tf.stack([i1, i2, indices], axis=-1)
    # Get scatter-added tensor
    scatter = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add(tensor, idx, updates)
    return scatter
```